# How can I change an image with another keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-manipulation

I have the following HTML code:

```
<img id="Card00" src="images/words/back.png" onclick="imageClicked(0,0);">
```

And the following Javascript code:

```
function ShowImage(id, row, column)
{
    var imagePath = 'images/words/' + id + '.png';
    var imgId = '#Card' + row + '' + column;

    $(imgId).attr('src', imagePath);
    var width = $(imgId).attr('width');
    var height = $(imgId).attr('height');

    if (width > height)
        $(imgId).attr('width', 200);
    else
        $(imgId).attr('height', 200);
}
```

`imageClicked` only calls `ShowImage`.

`Back.png` is 200x200. I want to change back.png image with another one. That another one `(id + .png)`, is bigger than 200x200, so I need to resize it on `ShowImage` function.

But I can't do that, because I can't get its new width and height in this piece of code:

```
var width = $(imgId).attr('width');
var height = $(imgId).attr('height');
```

My goal is to change `back.png` image with another one, keeping aspect radio.

And there is another problem: first I see the bigger image, and then, sometimes, it gets 200x200. I said sometimes because sometimes I get its width or its height.

Any advice?

Comment: Hello....   did you ever look at any of these answers?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is just load the image into memory first, then once it loads get its real height and width, use that info -- URL, height and width -- to determine the appropriate dimensions. Note that this isn't foolproof, though, as caching can mess it up.

Note that you can generalize the below to include maximum dimensions in the function itself, but I think it's pretty easily adaptable:

```
// Example: replaceImage($("img#someID"), "http://example.com/logo.png");

var MAX_HEIGHT = 80;
var MAX_WIDTH = 80;

function keepAspectRatio(temp, $target, url) {
  // Get height and width once loaded
  var realHeight = temp.height;
  var realWidth = temp.width;

  // Get how much to divide by (1 if image fits in dimensions)
  // Get rid of ", 1" if you just want everything to be either
  // MAX_HEIGHT tall or MAX_WIDTH wide
  var factor = Math.max(realHeight/MAX_HEIGHT, realWidth/MAX_WIDTH, 1);
  realHeight /= factor;
  realWidth /= factor;

  // Set the target image's source, height and width
  $target.attr("src", url).css({height: realHeight, width: realWidth});
}

function replaceImage($target, url) {
  $("<img>").load(function() {
    keepAspectRatio(this, $target, url);
  }).attr("src", url);
}
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x9mhs/4/)

**EDIT**

Swapped places of `attr` and `load` per the comment below. I'm not going to go too crazy with optimization beyond that, as what we'd really do if we wanted things perfect would be to preload everything, get its real dimensions, and use that information each time we change the original image.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I would call .load() function before setting attribute; because if attr() happens superfast them you'll miss your handler.

Comment: Also this code is not optimized, because each time image is clicked a new handler is bound to the image.load(). In order to avoid this you need to make the function a named function and first unbind("load", func) and then bind("load", func);

Comment: @user Definitely true on load() before attr(). Thanks for pointing that out. While I agree that you could optimize things further, though, in practical terms this answers the question of _how_ you get the real height and width and maintain aspect ratio, and beyond that it's the asker's job to tailor its use to his/her application.

Comment: @Bryan: thanks for your answer. If I have asked this is because I'm very very new in JavaScript. So I don't know if this code is optimized and if I can optimize your code.

Comment: @Vans The optimization being discussed here will have a minimal impact on the end-user, less than a millisecond or so. You certainly _could_ optimize it in the extreme, but I would prioritize simplicity and maintainability.

Comment: @Bryan: I have to change this line `$target.attr("src", url).css({height: realHeight, width: realWidth});` with this `$(target).attr("src", url).css({height: realHeight, width: realWidth});`. And also, I've changed this: `function keepAspectRatio(temp, $target, url)` with this one `function keepAspectRatio(temp, target, url)` to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
var width = $(imgId).clientWidth;
var height = $(imgId).clientHeight;
```